# Were the innocent spared in Deuteronomy 13:15?

Tags: israel, deuteronomy

> Deuteronomy 13:15: You shall surely put the inhabitants of that city to the sword, devoting it to destruction, all who are in it and its cattle, with the edge of the sword.

Some scholars interpret this to mean they only killed the guilty parties, but it doesn't read that way to me.

A city (or town, as some versions indicate) could be a very large place, large enough that there could be many people who were completely unaware of idolatry practices within the city, many who would have abhorred them, who might have even been co-operative in an investigation to find idolaters.

Why does it read as though these people are put to death also?

Comment: Did not Lot ask that Sodom and Gomorrah be spared if there were to be  found 10 good men. There were not even 10 men of good repute to be found

Comment: @KenGraham That was Abraham, and yes, but that doesn't explain why the law is that any city containing any number of idolaters would be destroyed by the hands of man.

Comment: If the cattle weren't spared, well, you can assume that no humans were either.

Comment: @DerÜbermensch That doesn't follow. Cattle were property. Humans were citizens.

Comment: Exactly. Being animals, they were innocent and could have been used for breeding more cattle for food, leather, etc. Why destroy them?

Comment: The destruction of property is not the killing of an innocent, it is the wastage of resources. If you destroy everything someone owns, then nobody gains anything material. Then there is less incentive to falsely accuse. Also, there is the whole ‘unclean things not to be used for clean purposes’ philosophy.

Comment: "then you must inquire, probe and investigate it thoroughly". Everyone in the town was evil. Period. Sodom and Gomorrah would like to speak to you.

Comment: @AngelusVastator Which town would this be?

Comment: The hypothetical town of Deuteronomy 13:15.

Comment: @AngelusVastator This is a general principle being set out. Of course not every inhabitant will have worshipped false gods!

Comment: This question would be better if the scholars who offered the different interpretation were listed and some information provided so that it could be responded to

Answer (score 1):

Can any human be capable to judge in God position who is innocent and who isn't? Definitely no one. So how could the innocent be spared?

In Genesis chapter 19, it recorded a total destruction of Sodom and Gomorrah. Abraham niece Lot and his family was told by two angels to leave the city and saved, except his wife who looked back and became a pillar of salt.

Genesis 19:29 NIV

> So when God destroyed the cities of the plain, he remembered Abraham, and he brought Lot out of the catastrophe that overthrew the cities where Lot had lived.

So God could brought out the innocent people from the city before the destruction, it is not necessary for us to further question about it. Isaiah 40:13 read

> Who can fathom the Spirit of the Lord,
> or instruct the Lord as his counselor?

So just follow His word and do not doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Were the innocent spared is a very complex question that will require a complex answer.

What do we know about the immediate context of this passage?

> 12 “If you hear in one of your cities, which the Lord your God is
>   giving you to live in, anyone saying that 13 some worthless men have
>   gone out from among you and have seduced the inhabitants of their
>   city, saying, ‘Let us go and serve other gods’ (whom you have not
>   known), 14 then you shall investigate and search out and inquire
>   thoroughly. If it is true and the matter established that this
>   abomination has been done among you, 15 you shall surely strike the
>   inhabitants of that city with the edge of the sword, utterly
>   destroying it and all that is in it and its cattle with the edge of
>   the sword

First, a thorough inquiry was done to validate the claim.  The specific claim is that the inhabitants were seduced to serve other gods.  The logical conclusion would appear to be that if the inhabitants were not seduced then the city would be spared.  It could be the case that during the inquiry the people not guilty could have been removed from the judgement however that's not stated or indicated from the text.

Here's where it gets complex:  Let's imagine for a moment that there were innocent people who were not seduced to serve other gods maybe along with women and children.  What happens to these people who die?  To answer this question it helps to understand the rest of the Bible and to ask:  When a person dies, whether they are 2 or 82 for whatever reason is God committing murder?

If we study our Bible well we can conclude the following:

1. When a person dies on earth they are simply changing locations
2. If there is any unjust suffering in this life, God more than makes up for it in eternity.  Romans 8:18
3. God is faithful to keep His promises
4. God created life on earth and it's good, however life with Him will be much better (no more pain, suffering, death, and sin.)

Comment: Your justification boils down to 'the good go to heaven'. True, this means that the eternal souls of the saved are not at risk, but that's not what I'm asking. What purpose does it serve to kill people for living in the same city as idolaters? Why is it that people are able to get away with any minor crimes whatsoever without being put to death, but those who live in a city where wickedness takes place are put to death?

Comment: This is why this is a complex question.  I don't believe that the good go to heaven.  God credits those righteous who place their faith in Him so to that extent they would be "innocent".  Since we do not know how the inquiry works we don't know if the innocent are warned, rescued, or caught up in the judgement.  Assuming that if the are innocent "righteous through faith" are caught up in the judgment then we know that God is faithful to see to it that they are compensated.  God is holy beyond what we understand and He takes the first commandment seriously.

Comment: The people who are made good by God go to heaven. So what? Are you saying they (they being those innocent of this particular crime) were killed or weren’t killed? If they were, what purpose could this possibly serve? If God does not delight in punishing the guilty, how much less does he delight in punishing the innocent? And if they weren’t, why does the text read as though everyone died?

Comment: Given that there's an inquiry means that God's goal is to make sure innocent people are not being caught up in this specific judgement.  The text does not elaborate beyond that point.  If we assume that there are innocent being caught in this judgement as well we are not given the reason why or a purpose.  Therefore we go by what we do know about the character and ability of God to reward the faithful after their loss of life on earth.  My uncle was on a mission trip and his car was hit by a drunk driver and he died.  There's so much we are not able figure out so we rest in the ability of God.

Comment: But wouldn't an inquiry actively weed out the believer and non-believer? I'm sure there would be confessions.

Answer (score 0):

God did not and won't tolarate worship of Demons among his people:-

> NWT  Psalm 106:34-38  "**They did not annihilate the peoples, As Jehovah had commanded them. 35 But they mingled with the nations And adopted their ways. 36 They kept serving their idols**, And these became a snare to them. 37 ***They would sacrifice their sons And their daughters to demons. 38 They kept spilling innocent blood, The blood of their own sons and daughters Whom they sacrificed to the idols of Caʹnaan; And the land was polluted with bloodshed.***

To keep his worship and people clean from child sacrefice and ritual immorality and homage to Satans angels, the Demons, he said that the Israelites must exterminate ALL false worshipers out of the land regardless of who they were so he could give The Promised Land to the desendants of Abraham as being clean from Devil worship, as we know it today:-

> NWT  Deuteronomy 13:12-18
>
> “In case you hear it said in one of your cities that Jehovah your God is giving you to occupy, 13 ‘Good-for-nothing men have gone out among you to turn away the inhabitants of their city, saying: ***“Let us go and serve other gods,” gods*** that you have not known,’ 14 you should look into the matter, making a thorough investigation and inquiry; and if it is confirmed to be true that this detestable thing has been done among you, 15 **you should without fail strike down the inhabitants of that city with the sword. Devote it and everything that is in it, including its livestock, to destruction by the sword**. 16 You should then collect all its spoil into the middle of its public square and burn the city with fire, and its spoil will serve as a whole offering to Jehovah your God. It will become a permanent heap of ruins. It should never be rebuilt. 17 Your hand should take nothing that was set apart for destruction, so that Jehovah may turn away from his burning anger and show you mercy and compassion and multiply you, just as he has sworn to your forefathers. **18 For you should obey Jehovah your God by keeping all his commandments that I am commanding you today, thus doing what is right in the eyes of Jehovah your God.**

His command was:-

> NWT  The First Commandment Exodus 20:1-6  "Then God spoke all these words:
>
> 2 “I am Jehovah your God, who brought you out of the land of Egypt, out of the house of slavery. 3 You must not have any other gods besides me.
>
> 4 “YOU MUST NOT make for yourself a carved image or a form like anything that is in the heavens above or on the earth below or in the waters under the earth. 5 You must not bow down to them nor be enticed to serve them, for I, Jehovah your God, am a God who requires exclusive devotion, bringing punishment for the error of fathers upon sons, upon the third generation and upon the fourth generation of THOSE WHO HATE ME, 6 but showing loyal love to the thousandth generation of those who love me and keep my commandments.

God was not going to tolarate hatred of him in The Promised Land (the land of Abraham) were He was going to be worshiped.

Comment: Exterminating false worshippers is one thing. But exterminating everyone who lives in the same city as false worshippers is something else.

Comment: @Piomicrom That depends if we have God's view of matter or a human view of matters.   NWT  Isaiah 55:8, 9  “For my thoughts are not your thoughts, And your ways are not my ways,” declares Jehovah.  9 “For as the heavens are higher than the earth, So my ways are higher than your ways And my thoughts than your thoughts.

Comment: Are you saying that God sees these things as the same?

Comment: @Piomicron  Exodus 34:7 " . . .he will by no means leave the guilty unpunished, bringing punishment for the error of fathers upon sons and upon grandsons, upon the third generation and upon the fourth generation.”  There are results of worship for good or bad and they will arrive!

Comment: “Fathers shall not be put to death because of their children, nor shall children be put to death because of their fathers.” (Deuteronomy 24:16)

Comment: @Piomicron But the reap the legecy left behind such a pagan worship in the family, thus punishment will still come.

Comment: Okay? But why then would sons of the idolaters, along with many others be put to death for the crimes of a few?

Comment: @Piomicron Community responsability!  Example Noah's Day; only him aand his family came out of the Flood; every other human being young and old died & the 10th plauge in Egypt!

Comment: Those two were different. They were God taking judgement on specific groups of people. To implement a GENERAL law of killing an entire city if idolaters are found in it is something else. Also, it makes no pragmatic sense if it truly is the way I read it! Why would you ever want to acknowledge idolaters in your community if it meant that your entire community along with yourself would be put to death under the law if that happened?

Comment: @Piomicron last ones now Sodom & Gomorrah  & Jersualem in 70CE & Jericho & then in Armageddon when non worshipers of God will all be removed of the earth.

Comment: Again, divine judgement, except I'm not sure the siege of Jerusalem had any divine intervention or mandate?

Answer (score 0):

Were the innocent spared in Deuteronomy 13:15?

Yes, according to Matthew Poole's Commentary:

> The inhabitants of that city, to wit, all that are guilty, not the innocent part, such as disowned this apostacy, who doubtless by choice and interest, at least upon warning, would come out of so wicked and cursed a place.

Particularly the little children who didn't know demons from the true God.

Why does it read as though these people are put to death also?

To demonstrate the fierce anger of the Lord:

> 17 Then the Lord will turn from his fierce anger

If you don't want to get killed, leave the city as quickly as possible and don't bother your belongings.

> 16 You are to gather **all the plunder** of the town into the middle of the public square and completely burn the town and all its plunder as a whole burnt offering to the Lord your God. That town is to remain a ruin forever, never to be rebuilt

Answer (score 0):

The commandment was to slaughter all of them and burn everything. The key word is חרם, which is often translated as "utterly destroy" or "devote to destruction" or "devote to YHWH" and it means exactly what you think -- an irrevocable, unappealable sentence of death. There is no scholarly ambiguity about this word, and it is used in both military and sacrificial texts:

Leviticus 27:29 (KJV)

> 29 None **devoted**, which shall be **devoted** of men, shall be
> redeemed; but shall surely be put to death.

TDOT has a lengthy and exhaustive discussion, with the following conclusion:

> The hiphil of ḥrm means “consecrate something or someone as a
> permanent and definitive offering for the sanctuary; in war,
> consecrate a city and its inhabitants to destruction; carry out this
> destruction; totally annihilate a population in war; kill.” The hophal
> means “be condemned to capital punishment with certain additional
> conditions; the execution of this punishment; confiscation (of
> property) (?).” The noun ḥērem I means “the object or person
> consecrated in the sense of the hiphil or condemned in the sense of
> the hophal or contaminated by entering into their deadly sphere; the
> act of consecration or of extermination and killing.” The usual
> translation, “ban,” is and always has been false and misleading. It
> was an appropriate rendering of the medieval Jewish ḥērem,
> corresponding to secular outlawry and ecclesiastical excommunication,
> but is based on a later development of the word ḥērem that is
> unattested in the OT.

It did not matter if some were not idol worshippers (we have no way of knowing how many were) because judgment was pronounced on the nation as a whole, not on individual members.

This is something hard for moderns to accept, but the text is clear and should not be altered because it offends the tastes of the reader.

Although I believe if a member of one of the seven condemned tribes fled the holy land, they would no longer be under a death sentence, since the goal was to purify the land of these foreign nations rather than to kill the people per se.

There are other examples of escape, for example Rahab defected to Israel, and even became one of the ancestors of Christ, which is more proof that this was not so much about any individuals being condemned as the tribe being condemned. If you defected and joined a different tribe, the condemnation would not follow you. Of course, there were not many opportunities to defect.

Note that Rahab was a prostitute, but she was saved because she helped Israel, whereas someone who was more upright by man's standards but did not help Israel was killed, proving again that whether you lived or died had little do with your own behavior other than whose side you were on. In this sense, it is like the blood of the passover lamb, where even the most guilty firstborn sons were exempt from death if they had the sign on their doorpost, while innocent infants were killed merely for being firstborn sons and not having the sign on their doorpost.

---

Norbert Lohfink, “חָרַם,” ed. G. Johannes Botterweck and Helmer Ringgren, trans. David E. Green, Theological Dictionary of the Old Testament (Grand Rapids, MI; Cambridge, U.K.: William B. Eerdmans Publishing Company, 1986), 188.

Answer (score 0):

The cattle, which means all animals, were innocent creatures. No they were not spared, so neither were the children.  Children are innocent by man’s definitions, but every child born of Adam’s seed is a sinner and guilty under the Law.